# PHP Update datetime with session

Tags: php, session

I use the following to update when a user logs in.. but this only works if they log in.. I have a remember me function and if checked user does not have to login.. and then it don't update..

is there a way to use the users session ID to update the last activity?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET DateLastVisit = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $Date);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to match the activity with the user id as without this, you will end up updating every users record.

Try this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){//check if we already have a session at the moment
  session_start();
}
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];//change to your session id key
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET DateLastVisit = ? WHERE id_user = ?");//change id_user to what you have in your database
/*always check whether the prepare() succeeded */
if ($stmt === false) {
  trigger_error($db->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $Date, $user_id); // we bind the user_id as well
    $stmt->execute(); //execute, returns true/false
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

when user login,set a token for this user,and give this token TTL,save this to your table.then,you can check user login state with token,once  ttl expired,rebuild a new token and ttl.